# Alinhamento Conteúdo Table HTML5

Tags: html5, tabela-html, css

Boa tarde pessoal,

alguém sabe me dizer qual alteração falta no meu código para que minha tabela fique com dados embaixo da coluna mostrada na foto?

**Segue abaixo foto do resultado esperado e do meu código:**

[image: tabela]

**index.html**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Pacientes</th>
            <th>Como estou?</th>
            <th>Administrar Paciente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 

        <tr>
            <tr><td>Maria</td></tr>
            <tr><td>João</td></tr>
            <tr> <td>Joana</td></tr>
        </tr>

        <td>
            <tr>
                <tr> <td>Sequencia de imagens (selecionada bem)</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>Sequencia de imagens (selecionada mal)</td> </tr>
                <tr> <td>Sequencia de imagens (selecionada mal)</td> </tr>
            </tr>
        </td>

        <tr>
            <tr><td> <a href="viewPatient.html" id="viewPatient"> <img id="viewPatientIcon" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png" alt="eye icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="editPatient.html" id="editPatient"> <img id="editPatientIcon" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/software-menu-icons/256/SoftwareIcons-68-512.png" alt="pen icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td></tr>
            <tr><td><a href="deletePatient" id="deletePatient"> <img id="deletePatientIcon" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/basic-ui-elements-coloricon/21/19-512.png" alt="delete icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a></td></tr>  
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode criar uma div em volta da lista e utilizar css para modificar a posição

Comment: Aqui ensina como usar css: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: E aqui ensina a modificar posição:https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na estrutura que você criou para montar a tabela, tente desta forma:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>Pacientes</th>
           <th>Como estou?</th>
           <th>Administrar Paciente</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>Maria</td>
           <td>Sequencia de imagens (selecionada bem)</td>
           <td> <a href="viewPatient.html" id="viewPatient"> <img id="viewPatientIcon" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png" alt="eye icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td>João</td>
           <td>Sequencia de imagens (selecionada mal)</td>
           <td> <a href="viewPatient.html" id="viewPatient"> <img id="viewPatientIcon" src="https://freeiconshop.com/wp-content/uploads/edd/eye-outline.png" alt="eye icon" width="30" height="30"/> </a> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que cada TR representa toda a linha da tabela, e cada TD representa cada célula, cada dado que faz parte da mesma linha.